# Email field filled in automatically when viewing user profile page in Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, forms, email, devise

I have a Rails app that allows users to create an account (handled by Devise). I have a custom login form in the header of the website. The issue is that the email field in the form is automatically filled in with the email address of the User displayed in the show page.

For example: Browsing the website, land on Jim's profile page when logged out. The email field in the login form will display Jim's email address.

It's a very odd bug and this only happens when you view a specific User profile page. Here's the login form in the header:

```
<%= form_for(:user, :url => session_path(:user)) do |f| %>
      <%= f.text_field :email, :style => "width:125px;", :placeholder => "email" %>
      <%= f.password_field :password, :style => "width:125px;", :placeholder => "password" %>
      <%= f.check_box :remember_me %><%= f.label :remember_me, :class => "checkbox inline", :style => "color: white; font-size: 12px" %>  
      <%= f.submit 'Log in', :class => "btn btn-primary btn-small" %>
      <%= link_to "Forgot password?", new_password_path(:user), :style => "font-size: 12px; color: white" %>
```

I created the above form using this guide:

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Display-a-custom-sign_in-form-anywhere-in-your-app

Any ideas on how to fix this? Thanks!

Comment: Does your page have a `@user` instance variable?  If so I believe the form is being scoped to that variable versus a new user instance.

Comment: Yes, it does. What should I do? Do I have to rename the instance variable?

Comment: I would try that and see if that resolves your issues, I imagine it will

Comment: That worked, thanks! Be sure to post the answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the instance variable on the page to something other than @user. It is conflicting with the form_for :user that you are using as this creates or uses an instance variable with the same name. Since you have a @user variable it uses that and populated the fields it has on record.